# Can't get ATTR value from IMG SRC using EACH (jquery)

Tags: jquery, each, attr

The 'each' function returns 3 times undefined while I am trying to get 3 different results with 3 different URLS.

```
var src = $('img').each(function(){
    $(this).attr("src");
alert(src);
    });
```

I found a couple of answer on S.O. but none of them seems to answer this (really basic) problem.

What I want to do is replace every img url with a more specific URL

ex:

```
a.jpg --> a-ok.jpg
b.jpg --> b-ok.jpg
c.jpg --> c-ok.jpg
```

That's why I need the URL of all the img using an EACH.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is wrong. By assigning `src` variable to `$('img').each` you will get elements collection, not `src` attributes.

Should be:

```
$('img').each(function(){
  var src = $(this).attr("src");
  alert( src );
});
```

To replace `src` attributes you will need do this inside `each` callback function.

For example like this:

```
$('img').each(function(){
  var src = $(this).attr("src");
  $(this).attr("src", src.replace('.', '-ok.'));
});
```

Comment: There can be any number of dots in image name so use: `replace('.jpg','-ok.jpg')`

Comment: It was just for example. I guess OP wants something totally different.

Comment: There's only one thing that is wrong, src should be set inside. I think `totally wrong` is uncalled for

Comment: You could also get use of passing a function to `.attr` : http://jsfiddle.net/9m51f171/. Which is shorter and clearer (but slower if i am not mistaken).

Comment: I see my mistake now, should have create the variable inside the each function. thanks a lot, everybody.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').each(function(){
  var src = $(this).attr("src");
  console.log( src );
  // now override the src 
  var pos = src.lastIndexOf("."); // there can be numerous . in the url
  $(this).attr('src', ( src.substring(0,pos) + '-OK.'+src.substring(pos+1) ) ) ;
});
```

Comment: `src.substring(0,pos) `- what is `pos` ?